# Display rows from mySQL using PHP prepared statement with binding

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**The following code works but I am concerned about SQL injection.**

I am attempting to pass a parameter `$S` to some PHP code in order to display test results. Working code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $S = $_GET['S'];
    // $sql = "SELECT `date`, `test` FROM `results` WHERE `id` = \"003-26\"";
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "slowLearner";
    $password = "myPassword";
    $dbname = "myDataBase";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check if id exists 
    if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `date`, `test` FROM `results` WHERE `id` = ?"))){
        die("Prepare1 failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error);
    }

    if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $S)){
        die("Binding1 parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `date`, `test` FROM `results` WHERE `id` = '".$S."'";
    // But I believe the line above is prone to SQL injection so 
    // IDEALLY I would prefer to use something like:
    // $result = $conn->query($stmt);
    // but that simply does not work... (zero results is displayed)
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "Test Date: " . $row["date"]. ",  Test score: " . $row["test"]. " (s)" . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "zero results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

My comments in the code show where I am trying *(and failing)* to use a prepared statement with binding... I'm going around in circles with this, any help much appreciated.

**To clarify:**

There are no errors as such - when I try to use binding I simply don't get any results and the message zero results is displayed from the `else` part of `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`

I am certain that it is incorrect to have the `$sql` as well as `$stmt` as ultimately the way `$sql` is written makes it prone to injection... what I am trying to show is how far I have gotten with binding and at which point I become stuck.

**Modified Code:**

Based on [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) I modified the code (see below). But the output still says `zero results` even though I know there are 4 rows that match the query:  `$result = $conn->query($sql);`. Modified code as follows:

```
if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $S)){
    die("Binding1 parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->fetch();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

TIA -SL

Comment: There is an [example in the PHP docs for mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) that shows you how to query. Your attempt is indeed prone to SQL injection, what you're looking for is `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: Which error are you seeing?  I show a stmt and a query running

Comment: @Forbs - no errors as such, have updated the question to clarify.  Thanks

Comment: @ccKep - I have tried `$stmt->execute()` but without success, there simply is NOT enough room to list all the things I've tried :-(  I'll look at the link, thanks

Comment: @ccKep - I've updated the question with modified code but still no luck.

Comment: In your "Modified Code" part, you are using `bind_result()` incorrectly. Please read the documentation carefully

Comment: @Phil - thanks. In light of the answer from Spencer I see what you mean, but I could have stared at that documentation for another day without seeing what you meant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer... don't use `query`,  use `execute`

After the `prepare` and the `bind`

```
if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $S)){
   die("Binding1 parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}
```

use `execute` and check the return (if the return is FALSE then an error has occurred. if its successful, a SELECT should return a resultset)

```
// http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
   die("execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}
```

If we aren't using mysqlnd (native driver), then we can't use `get_result` to return the result set.

Optionally, we could do a `store_result`, recognizing that a large resultset will require a large amount of memory. If we don't do this, we can still fetch rows. (Its a performance / memory tradeoff.)

```
// http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php
$stmt->store_result();
```

We can fetch rows into bind result variables

```
// http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
$stmt->bind_result($r_date, $r_test);
```

The `fetch` function gets a row and populates our bind result variables. Note that these are references to scalar variables; `fetch` does not return a "resultset" object like `query` does.

```
$cnt = 0;
while($stmt->fetch()) {
   echo "Test Date: " . $r_date . ",  Test score: " . $r_test . " (s)" . "<br>";
   $cnt++;
}
if($cnt === 0) {
   echo "zero results";
}
```

If we did a `store_result`, we should free up the memory

```
$stmt->free_result();
```

And we don't always need to do a `close` of the statement, but its the normative pattern; and this handles those cases where we actually do need to do it.

```
// http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
$stmt->close();
```

---

If we are using mysqlnd (native driver) then we could use `mysqli_stmt_get_result` to return a resultset, like we get using `query`.

Whether or not to use `get_result` depends on how portable your code will need to be; if your codes is going to require mysqlnd.

Personally, I'd use PDO rather than mysqli.

Comment: You can save a lot of return-type checking by setting MySQLi to throw exceptions (just like PDO) ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)`

Comment: @Phil: thanks for the tip. OP code was already doing checks of the return, so I continued in that pattern. Important point is that the code shouldn't put it's figurative pinky finger to the corner of its mouth, Dr.Evil style "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?"

Comment: It's better not to continue this pattern as using die to report errors shouldn't be used anyway

Comment: @YourCommonSense certainly you are correct, the code could be modified to replace `die` with actions to perform logging, and more appropriate error handling. I could have demonstrated that, but I think that would have detracted from what SlowLearner was asking. I could have chosen to follow a pattern of *not* checking for any errors at all. And I think that would be even more wrong. At least with the `die`, we are doing *something* with the error. And it's easy enough to come back in and find and replace those actions. (I applaud SlowLearner's efforts to mitigate against SQL Injection.)

Comment: @spencer7593 - I appreciate very much that you stuck with the pattern that I have (apparently) been using incorrectly.  It helped me to fix my code and all is working now.  This is my 2nd attempt at doing anything with mySQL and PHP.   Being so new to this I was horrified to learn about SQL injection and thought I was doing well to take measures against that.  I'm very much open to rewriting using PDO or understanding other ways to improve.

Comment: You attitude, shared by many stackoverflowees, is one of reasons why most of PHP codes are still ugly in 2017. It costs you nothing to write a better code but you insist on using outdated and harmful approach

Comment: @YourCommonSense  Thank you for flattery, but I don't really believe that "my attitude" has all that much bearing on "why most PHP codes are still ugly". I think "my attitude" probably has more influence on the angular velocity of the earths rotation than it does on PHP code. Please feel free to contribute a better answer. Downvote this answer. Edit it. Flag it for moderator attention. Whatever it is that makes you feel all warm and cuddly. You be you.

Comment: @SlowLearner...  SQL Injection vulnerabilities are *prevalent*, and at the same time, so *easily* mitigated. I applaud your efforts. As an industry, we *know* the problem, and we *know* the solution; yet it's perennially number one in the OWASP Top Ten list... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @slow then rewrite it, PDO will save you a lot of headache

Comment: The question identified as a duplicate, the code in the question and in the answer doesn't do *any* checking for errors from `prepare` or `execute`, with no mention of detecting an error condition. While this may appear to be prettier PHP code than the "ugly" code in my answer, I think the code in that answer is *more* ugly in its omission of error checking. And that answer also uses the `numrows` which YourCommonSense dis-recommends as "a useless thing".

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have started already. I tried to use your PDO tutorial. It is not written for beginners so I have to find something that will help me bridge the gap or ask another question. By the way, I think you unfairly marked my question as a duplicate - I don't really care, but that other question while similar had different issues and did not make much attempt to isolate the problem.

Comment: @YourCommonSense here is (I think) a great introduction to PDO in case you were looking for one: https://www.taniarascia.com/create-a-simple-database-app-connecting-to-mysql-with-php/

Comment: @SlowLearner there is nothing great in this introduction, it is written by a very novice, and it is full of outdated and dangerous practices, one of which a textbook case of SQL injection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - hmmm that's too bad. Let me know if you find a tutorial that is suitable for beginners. Cheers

Comment: @SlowLearner I myst correct myself, there is no direct SQL injection in this particular code, there is only a code snippet that could be potentially dangerous.